# Line graphics opaqueness issue

Tags: graphics

[image: Example of Semi Transparent Line Crossing Issue]

When I plot with `Line[]` and `Opacity[.2]` where the lines cross \ darkens, I would like to be able to plot a consistent opaque level. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, 

correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: It actually looks more random than just darkening at crossings to me. The third vertical stripe from the right for instance. I've seen this before in `ListPlot` when there is no overlap, and the dark spots seem to have a regular spacing.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide an explicit code sample that we could work on. Some people have already voted this question to be closed as not specific enough. I think it is a good question and an interesting problem, so I didn't vote to close it, but I agree that you should provide more details so that we could better help you.

Comment: Are you saying that entire figure should be a uniform color?  What if different color lines cross?

Comment: I would probably approach the problem by thinking of all of the lines as one layer and then trying to adjust the opacity of the entire layer rather than the lines themselves. Then if there's supposed to be something underneath it I would try to combine the two graphics.

Comment: I believe the question isn't clear enough. What you see is the consequence of using `Opacity[ ]`. If you don't want it, then don't use it (use an equivalent `RGBColor[ ]` instead)

Comment: I wouldn't call this an Opacity issue, as this is precisely how I would want Opacity to work. In the real world: If you stack optical filters stuff should become darker.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are asking, I think you need to work with rasters: Draw the lines with no opacity, `Rasterize` then set the opacity with `SetAlphaChannel` Simple example..

```
 Show[Graphics@{Disk[{30, 180}, 150]}, 
     SetAlphaChannel[# , ImageMultiply[ColorNegate@Binarize[#], .6]] &@
        Rasterize[
         Graphics[ {Thickness[1], Red, Line[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}], 
           Line[{{0, -2}, {0, 2}}] }]]]
```

Note now your line art is drawn in pixel space, so you need to do extra work to scale and align with other graphic objects.

[image]

for comparison, the opacity multiplies when graphic objects overlap.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Where applicable you can avoid this problem by rendering a single continuous line rather than multiple disjoint segments:

```
SeedRandom[1]
pts = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}];
pts2 = Partition[pts, 2, 1];

Graphics[{Thickness[0.1], Orange, Opacity[0.2], Line /@ pts2}]

Graphics[{Thickness[0.1], Orange, Opacity[0.2], Line @ pts}]
```

[image]